# I want to shape an image like this Flutter

Tags: flutter

[image: I want to shape an image like this]

```
ClipRRect(
    child: Image.asset(
        'lib/assests/shopping.jpg'),
  
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
  
),
```

Comment: Your image is not properly attached. Please edit it

Comment: What is the output of the above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this,

```
ClipRRect (
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
  child: Image.Asset('path')
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,

          )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use borderRadius : BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10));